# Converting a string into 3 character substrings

Tags: java

I have an assignment where we read from a text file of Covid-19 sequences. I have read in the first line as a string and now have to use a substring method to break down this line into groups of 3 characters that forms a codon sequence. I am having trouble visualizing how to break this down? This is the first line of the file and every 3rd letter makes a codon. What I have now is `testLine = scan.nextLine();`

`AGATCTGTTCTCTAAACGAACTTTAAAATCTGTGTGGCTGTCACTCGGCTGCATGCTTAG`

```
for (int i = 0; i < testLine.length(); i += 3)
        
        {
            String codon = testLine.substring(0,3);
            codonList.add(codon);
            
        }
        System.out.println(codonList);
```

I know I am close, the output from my code above prints the first codon AGA 20 times repeatedly. Here is the output:

`[AGA, AGA, AGA, AGA, AGA, AGA, AGA, AGA, AGA, AGA, AGA, AGA, AGA, AGA, AGA, AGA, AGA, AGA, AGA, AGA]`

Edit* I was able to get it with the help of everyone. The issue I am having now is replicating this for the whole file. I added a hasNext method and it doesn't seem to work the same way.

```
    while(scan.hasNext())
    testLine = scan.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < testLine.length(); i += 3)
    {   
        String codon = testLine.substring(i, i + 3);
        codonList.add(codon);
    }
    System.out.println(codonList);  
}
Here is my output with the hasnext added: 
[ATT, AAT, TTT, AGT, AGT, GCT, ATC]
```

Comment: What are the parameters of the `substring` method and what would you use to print the 4th to 6th char and the 7th to 9th char?

Comment: (0,3) will print postions 0-2. So the next would be (3,6), (9, 12). I tried  testLine.substring(0,3) + testLine.substring(6,9) etc. but wasn't getting anywhere with that.

Comment: `String codon = testLine.substring(i, (i + 3));`

Answer (score 2):

Just use the index in the loop to `substring`.

```
String codon = testLine.substring(i, Math.min(i + 3, testLine.length()));
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/e4sR3l)

`String#split` can also be used.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(testLine.split("(?<=\\G.{3})")));
```

**Explanation of the regex at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/7DZLd0/1):**

[image]

Comment: I'll try it! I was trying String codon = testLine.substring(0,3) + testLine.substring(6,9) etc. but wasn't getting anywhere with that. Thanks!

Comment: @iota That's not really pedagogic

Comment: We haven't learned about split yet, but I have seen it when googling for help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you were very close.
You need to use **i** instead of **0** in the loop.

Here is my solution in C#. I know you ask Java but I had a C# IDE open...

```
List<string> codonList = new List<string>();
string testLine = "AGATCTGTTCTCTAAACGAACTTTAAAATCTGTGTGGCTGTCACTCGGCTGCATGCTTAG";

for (int i = 0; i < testLine.Length; i += 3)    
{
    String codon = testLine.Substring(i, 3);
    codonList.Add(codon);
}

int cnt = 0;
foreach (string s in codonList)
{
    cnt++;
    if (cnt != codonList.Count)
    {
        Console.Write(s + ", ");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }                
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Thank you! I haven't learned c# yet, just c++. Very cool to see.

Comment: Just be carefull, the signature of Substring is a little different in Java and C#.
Java is "string substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)"
C# is    "string Substring (int startIndex, int length)". Happy coding !

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
    String testLine = "AGATCTGTTCTCTAAACGAACTTTAAAATCTGTGTGGCTGTCACTCGGCTGCATGCTTAG";
    List<String> codonList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String newTestLine = testLine;

    for (int i = 0; i < testLine.length(); i += 3) {
        newTestLine = testLine.substring(i);
        String codon = newTestLine.substring(0, 3);
        codonList.add(codon);
    }
    System.out.println(codonList);
```

Comment: This is very close to what I had. Good to see that I was close. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a one liner:

```
String[] parts = testLine.split("(?<=\\G...)");
```

This works by splitting at points in the input that are 3 characters after the end of the last match (denoted by `\G`, which is initialized to start of input).

If you really need a List:

```
List<String> parts = Arrays.asList(testLine.split("(?<=\\G...)"));
```

Comment: @BohemianThe assignment is to store each codon into an array list. The issue I am having now is that when adding a hasNext method to the file, it makes my testLine variable uninitialized and I don't know why.

while(scan.hasNext())
  testLine = scan.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < testLine.length(); i += 3)
        {
            String codon = testLine.substring(i, i + 3);
            codonList.add(codon);
        }
        System.out.println(codonList);  
 }

Comment: @Ikefactor is it that each line read by the scanner should produce a List of 3-char strings, and the final result should be a List of those?

Comment: Yes. I then have to search for a specific one and then find the % of the entire sequence for two of the Codons.